# UILabel does not register touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a problem, I want to drag a label with finger, and I can't even register a touch on it. What can be a problem? self is my viewcontroller and self.label is my label.

EDIT:

My label is made programmatically over an uiimageview. UserInteractionEnables is set to YES.
I am not sure what is wrong, here is code in its entirety:

Init:

```
  UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fish.jpg"];
    UIImageView *mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    self.view = mainImageView;
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    self.label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.label.text = @"Hello, World";
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

Dragging:

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if([[touch view] isEqual:self.label])
    {
        NSLog(@"touch on label");

        self.startLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.label];
        // startLocation is a CGPoint declare globaly in .h..and lblName is your UILabel
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if([touch view] == self.label)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.label];
        CGFloat dx = pt.x - self.startLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = pt.y - self.startLocation.y;
        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.label.center.x + dx, self.label.center.y + dy);

        self.label.center = newCenter;

    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I have also tried this code, but it doesn't work too. I think the problem is not in these methods but with registering touches.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.startLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.label];
    self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.label.center.x + point.x - self.startLocation.x, self.label.center.y + point.y - self.startLocation.y);
}
```

Comment: Is self.label an IBOutlet?  If so, check it's connected in Interface Builder.  Also, unsure on your implementation but why are you just grabbing 'anyObject' from the set, rather than iterating through it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you check "User Interaction Enabled" on the label in interface builder, or if you you doing it in code, `userInteractionEnabled=YES`

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your `touchesBegan` method. Is it getting called at all?

Comment: I managed to resolve my problem. I enabled user interaction on UIImageView and it all works now!

Answer (score 1):

By default, `UILAbel` does not respond to touches. You need to enable the `userInteractionEnabled` property.

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```